Can I ask this question about using Android as a GSM Gateway?
Is this the correct place to ask this question?

Is it possible to use an android mobile phone as the external phone line for Asterisk PBX?
I am looking to set up a home PBX and want to use my existing android smartphone as the external telephone line, instead of a PSTN line. Is this possible? I have seen conflicting reports.
I have seen https://stackoverflow.com/q/4723453/4162689 however it is quite old and has conflicting answers.

Previously asked a similar question on SU but it was marked as off topic, so I just want to check.

Based on my understanding of the question, looks like it's asking how to use an Android device to achieve something, which falls under Android usage and on-topic.
In fact, searching for gsm gateway is:q returned a few questions that look similar/duplicate to your question:

Android phone as a GSM gateway
Converting phone to SIP gateway

Please take a look at these questions if any of them answers your question.
Otherwise, feel free to post a new question and explain why they are not solving your question!
